# How to align column of mixed fractions (after whole number) in tabular?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, fractions

I have a table that has a column with mixed fractions (that is, whole number plus fraction part) as entries which I need to reproduce in latex. The problem is that the fraction part of the mixed number have differing widths because the size of the numbers involved is changing. I'd like to align the numbers just to the right of the whole number. Here is a short example that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c | c}
Truman  & $4\frac{1}{8}$    \\
Ford    & $33\frac{1}{16}$  \\
Clinton & $105\frac{7}{107}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I've tried made various attempts at a solution such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c | r l}
Truman  & $4$ &$\frac{1}{8}$   \\
Ford    & $33$&$\frac{1}{16}$  \\
Clinton & $105$&$\frac{7}{107}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

but no luck. Ideas how I can proceed?

Comment: if you want no space between the columns then `c|r@{}l` might be what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, David. Your comment was amazingly fast!!! And it seems to work. If you modify my example, I'll accept your answer. (PS I just now signed up for tex.SO and I don't know how to get the latex to display. It not in FAQ)

Comment: For the heading then, I'll need to use multicol.

Comment: @Dr.PersonPersonII - Presumably, you meant `\multicolumn`, not `multicol`.

Comment: `\multicolumn` yes, (your MWE doesn't have a heading though:-) or if you want to do it all in one column, aligned on the units digit then you could use `\dcolumn`.

Comment: Yes, \multicolumn. I already have a working version of example above... I don't have the rep, I guess, to post answer to my own question. It is \begin{tabular}{c |r@{}l}
President & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Waist} \\
\hline
Truman    & $\phantom{00}4$&$\frac{1}{8}$   \\
Ford      & $\phantom{0}33$&$\frac{1}{16}$  \\
Taft      &           $105$&$\frac{7}{107}$
\end{tabular} Thanks everyone! You are great.

Comment: You don't need the phantoms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}

\begin{tabular}{c | r l}
\textbf{Person}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Score}}\\
Truman  & $4$ &$\frac{1}{8}$   \\
Ford    & $33$&$\frac{1}{16}$  \\
Clinton & $105$&$\frac{7}{107}$
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{c | r@{}l}
\textbf{Person}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Score}}\\
Truman  & $4$ &$\frac{1}{8}$   \\
Ford    & $33$&$\frac{1}{16}$  \\
Clinton & $105$&$\frac{7}{107}$
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{c | D{.}{}{-1}}
\textbf{Person}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Score}}\\
Truman  & 4.\frac{1}{8}   \\
Ford    & 33.\frac{1}{16}  \\
Clinton & 105.\frac{7}{107}
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```

Comment: interesting third example. Thank you, David.